# Observable<void | AuthError>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I keep getting the following error: `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<void | AuthError>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'. Type 'void | AuthError' is not assignable to type 'Action'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Action'.`

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

```
  googleSignIn: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.GOOGLE_SIGNIN),
    map((action: authActions.GoogleSignIn) => action.payload),
    switchMap(() => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.googleSignIn());
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      return Observable.of(new authActions.AuthError({ error: err.message }));
    })
  );
```

**authService.googleSignIn()**

```
  googleSignIn() {
    this.logger.debug('Initialising desktop Google sign in');
    const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    let firstName = null;
    let lastName = null;
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(async (result) => {
      if (result) {
        firstName = result.additionalUserInfo.profile['given_name'];
        lastName = result.additionalUserInfo.profile['family_name'];
        const path = `/users/${result.user.uid}/`;
        const doc = await this.firebaseService.docExists(path);
        if (!doc) {
          this.userService.processNewUser(result, firstName, lastName);
        }
        if (doc) {
          this.logger.debug(`${firstName} ${lastName} is a returning desktop user`);
        }
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.simpleModalService.displayMessage('Oops', error.message);
    });
  }
```

Comment: It means that your method it supposed to return an Observable<Action>, but it returns either an Observable<void> (if there is no error), or an Observable<AuthError> (if there is an error).

Comment: `switchMap` is not returning an Observable<Action> instead it is returning an Observable<your API response>. I think you need to use `pipe` on `Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.googleSignIn());` and map to an action. Or depends on your app logic return an action.

Comment: I've added the code for `authService.googleSignIn()`, how do I map it to an action?

Comment: @methuselah Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.googleSignIn()).pipe(map(() => {//return your action....;Your code does not show what your desired action}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ngrx v8 you can do like this

The problem you have is you have to return an action from you effect

```
 getPost$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PostActions.LoadPost),
      switchMap(action => {
        return this.postService
          .getPost(action.postId)
          .pipe(
            map(
              (post: IPost) => PostActions.LoadPostSuccess({ post }), // here is what you need to return
              catchError(errors => of(PostActions.LoadPostFail(errors)))
            )
          );
      })
    )
  );
```